# Short cut way of collecting form input values using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I have a form that collects information from a user. The form is composed of 10 input text field. The individual value of input text field is accessed via `var first_name = $("#fname").val()` as an example and passed to `var postdata = {'fname':first_name};` and then passed to ajax with `url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>main_controller/save_data", data: postdata` then the controller function again will collect it. If I have 30 input text field and then used this way, it would take me a lot of time. What is the best way to pass numerous input field values using javascript in miniature way? Is there a shortcut for this? Thanks a lot. I have a sample code below.

Views:

```
<input class="input input-large" type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value=""/>
<input class="input input-large" type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value=""/>
<input class="input input-large" type="text" name="address" id="address" value=""/>
<input class="input input-large" type="text" name="age" id="age" value=""/>
<input class="input input-large" type="text" name="height" id="height" value=""/>
<input class="input input-large" type="text" name="gender" id="gender" value=""/>
<input class="input input-large" type="text" name="school" id="school" value=""/>
<input class="input input-large" type="text" name="course" id="course" value=""/>
<input class="input input-large" type="text" name="year" id="year" value=""/>
<input class="input input-large" type="text" name="date_of_birth" id="date_of_birth"
value=""/>

<button class="btn btn-success" id="save" name="save">Save</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#save").click(function(){
    var fname = $("#fname").val();
    var lname = $("#lname").val();
    var address = $("#address").val();
    var age = $("#age").val();
    var height = $("#height").val();
    var gender = $("#gender").val();
    var school = $("#school").val();
    var course = $("#course").val();
    var year = $("#year").val();
    var date_of_birth = $("#date_of_birth").val();

    var postdata = {
            'fname': fname,
            'lname': lname,
            'address': address,
            'age': age,
            'height': height,
            'gender': gender,
            'school': school,
            'course': course,
            'year': year,
            'date_of_birth': date_of_birth
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>main_controller/save_data",
        data: postdata,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.notify) {
                alert('success');
            } else {
                alert('Failed');
            }
        }
    });

    });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
function save_data(){
    $fname = $this->input->post('fname');
    $lname = $this->input->post('lname');
    $address = $this->input->post('address');
    $age = $this->input->post('age');
    $height = $this->input->post('height');
    $gender = $this->input->post('gender');
    $school = $this->input->post('school');
    $course = $this->input->post('course');
    $year = $this->input->post('year');
    $date_of_birth = $this->input->post('date_of_birth');
    $this->insert_model->save_data($fname,$lname,$address,$age,$height,$gender,$school,$course,$year,$date_of_birth);
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed there is:

```
$("#save").click(function () {

    var postData = $("#idOfYourForm").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>main_controller/save_data",
        data: postdata,

        // it is perhaps better to specify the dataType
        // of the data expected back from the server 
        // for readability
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.notify) {
                alert('success');
            } else {
                alert('Failed');
            }
        }
    });

    // maybe you need this
    return false;
});
```

**http://api.jquery.com/serialize/**

Comment: Hi! Do I need to change something in my controller function the way it does now if I use the serialize function?

Comment: Nope. The server gets the same request.

Comment: Is there a way too that I can do the same thing in controller function like what I did in the javascript function like serialize?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
var inputs, index;

inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
// get inputs[index] element.
}
```

You can get more information from the [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FNodeList) reference.

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery `serialize()` method
It effectively turns the form values(input/select..) into a valid querystring.

```
$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>main_controller/save_data",
   data:$('form').serialize(),
   success: function(data){
   if(data.notify){
   alert('success');
  }
  else{
   alert('Failed');
  }
 }
});
```

`serialize`() documentation:[link](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: Hi! Do I need to change something in my controller function the way it does now if I use the serialize function?

Comment: @Avelino No need to change anything on controller function

Comment: Is there a way too that I can do the same thing in controller function like what I did in the javascript function like serialize?

Comment: @Avelino In server side i.e. your controller function you have to get all your paramteres(what you are currently doing is fine)..however when you are calling $this->insert_model->save_data method ..you are passing large number of parameters (looks ugly and order of parameters matter..so error prone).I would suggest you to define a class which encapuslates all your post parameters and pass instance of that class in save_data method.you will have to modify save_data method for this purpose.

Comment: Yeah. what I did also as adjustment is I placed it in an array and place that array as parameter in save_data function. But still, a lot of parameters to placed in the array part. I just cant figure out how to define it in a class and encapsulate it just like what you are suggesting

Comment: @Avelino do something like `class MyData{ public $fname,$lname,$address,$age,$height,$gender,$school,$course,$year,$date_of_birth;}` and create instance of it as `$myData=new MyData()` and set the properties as `$myData->fname = $this->input->post('fname');` and do similiar for other post parameters and then finally do `$this->insert_model->save_data($myData);`..hope it helps!

Comment: So that is what you mean. I have another adjustment made also. I just made this <input type="text" name="user[fname]">,<input type="text" name="user[lname]"> and so on.. Then in the controller function, I just use this $data = $this->input->post('user'); then save_data($data); , that's it. Pretty working well. Anyway, thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: That is great..looks more awesome.

Answer (score 1):

```
var formelements = {}
$(input).each()
{
formelements[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
}
```

now all your values are stored inside the formelements, you can even send this element instead of manually sending all form elements:

```
$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>main_controller/save_data",
   data:formelements,
   dataType:"json",
   success: function(data){
   if(data.notify=="Success"){
   alert('success');
  }
  else{
   alert('Failed');
  }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Non-serialization alternative:**

If you need an array of form fields somewhere else in your script (for example, for client-side validation purposes) you can use the following alternative of `.serialize()`:

```
var postdata = {};
$(".input").each(function () {
  postdata[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
});
```

Now `postdata` contains the array of values (like in your initial code snippet) instead of querystring.

**P.S.:** Add some special class attribute to your form fields instead of `input` which I have used just for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fname=fname.value;
var lname=lname.value;
var address=address.value;
var age=age.value;
var height=height.value;
var date_of_birth=date_of_birth.value;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Please read "[answer]". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.